# How do I get the distinct/unique values in a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have a column with values, and I want to find out what distinct values are in there (not how many - but the actual distinct values), how can I do that?

In SQL Server I would do something like

```
SELECT Distinct(MyColumn) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel

Comment: Since fall 2018, this can now be done **much easier** using the `UNIQUE()` function (at least if you use Office 365). https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073902/12418842

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Simpler than you might think:

- Click the **Data** Ribbon Menu
- Select the **Advanced** Button in the *Sort & Filter* section
- Fill in the dialog Box, copying the results to another location and making sure you **tick Unique records only**

[image]

Comment: For those of us still living a ribbon-free existence, it's Data->Filter->Advanced.

Comment: +1 This method is superior to Remove Duplicates if you want to keep the original data intact.

Comment: If copying data to another sheet, you must initiate the Advanced dialog _from the sheet you want to copy to_, otherwise you get a `You can only copy filtered data to the active sheet` error.

Comment: This doesn't update when the source range values change. Is there any way to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 139):

**Excel 2007 and 2010:**
Use the `Remove Duplicates` menu option under the **Data** header.

**Excel 2003:**
Easy way:

1. Make sure your data has a header
2. Data --> Filter --> Advanced Filter
3. Check Unique Records Only
4. Select Copy to another location
5. Click OK

Hard way:

Write a macro with the following code:

```vb
'Remove duplicates from sorted list
Sub getDistinct()
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            ActiveCell.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

That gives you your distinct list.  You may want to copy your list to another sheet first.

Answer (score 27):

Or (a simple crude way):

In B1,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

and copy down. It just copies the first occurrence of each value across (in the row that it occurs in).

Comment: As with all Excel formulas, you may need to use semicolons (`;`) instead of commas (``,``) based on your system’s regional settings.

Answer (score 25):

I use two main methods to get distinct values - the first is the invaluable `Remove Duplicates` tool as [suggested by Nathan DeWitt](https://superuser.com/a/49618/151054).

The downside to `Remove Duplicates` is that you lose data. Despite the power of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> you may not wish to do this for various reasons - eg you may have filters currently selected that make it quite messy to remove duplicates to get your distinct list of values.

The other method, not mentioned above is to use a Pivot Table.

Let's say this is your table and you want to get the distinct list of Platforms.
[image: dummy table]

Insert a `Pivot Table` with the table as your data source.

Now select the **Platform(s)** column as your `Row Labels`.

Voila! A list of distinct values.

[image: pivot table as distinct value list]

If you wish to tidy this up, you can switch off `Field Headers` and set `Grand Totals` to be `Off for Rows and Columns`.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can include the filter option in a macro

```
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, the most simple way to sort is to use "Filter" option.

First step is to find the duplicate values with Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Duplicate Values.

Then click the arrow on the Column you have the duplicates (in this case "Platforms") -> Filter by Color (Cells color or font color).

Comment: The outcome here is different, as _all_ instances of duplicates are removed. E.g. the column with values `[a, a, b]` should reduce to `[a, b]`, not `[b]`.

Comment: @HugoIdeler, "all instances of duplicates are removed", exactly what I am needing!

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 365 we now have UNIQUE(), which returns an array of unique rows.

Comment: Thanks - I had not noticed this function appear. Could you expand your answer to explain how to use `UNIQUE()` please so anybody unfamiliar with Excel can apply this?