# Excel: how to count number of distinct values in a range with condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I read and tested quite a lot, but I still not able to come up with a solution for my problem.

The close solution I found is the second one proposed in article below:
[How to count number of distinct values in a range?](https://superuser.com/questions/189762/excel-how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range)

I'm essentially after finding out how many values are unique in Column A while Column B correspond to a certain value.

Let's imagine the following spreadsheet

```
COL A      COL B
abc        TRUE
abc        TRUE
bef        TRUE
bef        FALSE
hgf        TRUE
swd        FALSE
rth        FALSE
kjh        TRUE
```

I'd like to come up with a formula to calculate (not showing) the # of unique values in A
which contains TRUE in COL B.
So given the example above, I should get 4.

Now, I was expecting the formula below to be in some way helpful

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100))
```

once amended with a `COUNTIFS`, but it clearly doesn't work, and I don't understand why.
Also I don't really understand the reason of the initial bit: `A2:A100<>""`

Comment: Well, aside the fact that I work out on a different solution, no I'm not aware nor I cannot see any option to "accept" my favorite answer. I do normally vote the one that is helpful, but there is not "this is my answer" out of the many. Where is this?

Comment: Silly me. That's the big v sign underneath :)))

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table. No formulas required. Just a few clicks.

Drag column A (called "one" in my sample) to the row labels, drag column B (called "two" in my sample) to the column labels, drag any column into the values area and set the value calculation to "count".

One row above the pivot table, use a simple Count() function to return the count of uniques:

[image]

You can filter the pivot table to show only the items with "true" or only the items with "false".

Answer (score 2):

Try this "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B100=TRUE,IF(A2:A100<>"",MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))),ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: This is brilliant,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to list the values from Column `A` that have `"TRUE"` in column `B`.

In Cell `D2` enter this array formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and drag it down to display all the uniques that meet the condition...

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$9, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$9)+IF($B$2:$B$9<>TRUE, 1, 0), 0))`

Edit* Added a Photo.
[image]

Comment: Any reason for that $D1:D1 which is not part of my range?

Comment: When you drag the formula down that range (which is the cells above it) is used to identify what has already been returned so it won't return a duplicated value. See the photo I added to my answer if it helps.