# How to count unique numbers based on month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

Column A include a list of numbers, some are duplicated

Column B include a list  of numbers from 1-12 that represent the months

I need to count the unique numbers in column A where the month in column B = 1

Example:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
123     1
223     2
312     3
412     1
123     1
312     2
123     3
```

So here for example 123 show up twice when B=1 and 412 once on the same month so the unique count should be = 2

Comment: Please edit your question a bit by adding an example and your expected results, so that the others can help.

Comment: ColumnA              ColumnB
123   1
223   2
312   3
412   1
123   1
312   2
123   3
so here for example 123 show up twice when B=1 and 412 once on the same month so the unique count should be = 2

Comment: This thread has an answer http://superuser.com/questions/189762/how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range

Comment: unless I'm missing something it doesn't cover the month scenario

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a solution using countif, but I don't know if it can be done with only countif; So, as an alternative, this VBa does it

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountDuplicatesPerMonth()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Range("C:C").Value = "" 'clear the results


Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Dim val As String
    val = Range("A" & row).Value

    Dim month As Integer
    month = Range("B" & row).Value

    Range("C" & row).Value = 0

    Dim innerRow As Integer
    innerRow = 1

    Do While (Range("A" & innerRow).Value <> "")

        Dim innerVal As String
        innerVal = Range("A" & innerRow).Value

        Dim innerMonth As Integer
        innerMonth = Range("B" & innerRow).Value

        If (innerVal = val And innerMonth = month) Then
            Range("C" & row).Value = Range("C" & row).Value + 1
        End If

        innerRow = innerRow + 1

    Loop

   row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Before
[image]

After VBa runs

[image]

Comment: Without VBA: Put in cell C1 "=COUNTIF(A:A; "=" & B1)". Copy-paste down. Using string concatenating combined with cell references in Excel is very powerful and keeps you away from VBA. let me know if this works for you.