# Generating unique values in Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've got a list of entries in a range in LO Calc. The max size of the range is 1 X 9, but may include blanks and/or duplicates. How can I extract a list of unique values automatically, so that my user doesn't have to use the filter function?

Comment: Does [this q/a](http://superuser.com/q/238656/84724) solve your issue?

Comment: @tohuwawohu - that would be a logical approach but the question asks about a way to do it without using a filter.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if your 1×9 is one row × nine columns or vice versa. I chose the latter but it should not be very difficult to transpose this *array formula* solution.

[image: Unique Count in Calc]

The *array formula* in C2 is,

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(($A$2:$A$10<>"")/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10; $A$2:$A$10&"")); 0; ($A$2:$A$10<>"")/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10; $A$2:$A$10&"")))
```

*Array* formulas require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you plan to fill this right or down, you should adjust the absolute cell and cell range references to allow either a column or a row to 'float' in a relative manner. Once entered correctly, you can fill right or down as necessary.

**EDIT¹:**

OO Calc's `SUMPRODUCT` function can do this without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with this formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10<>"")/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10&""; $A$2:$A$10&""))
```

**EDIT²:**

The unique list can be gathered with a similar *array formula*.

[image: Unique list in OO CAlc]

The *array formula* in D2 is,

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(0; IF($A$2:$A$10<>""; COUNTIF(D$1:D1; $A$2:$A$10&""); 1); 0)); ""; INDEX($A$2:$A$10; MATCH(0; IF($A$2:$A$10<>""; COUNTIF(D$1:D1; $A$2:$A$10&""); 1); 0)))
```

This requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once entered correctly it can be filled down to gather all unique entries.