# Is there a way to find the two smallest numbers in a column in openoffice without repeats

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

The obvious but incorrect answer would be `Small(Range;2)` except that if there is more than 1 cell with the smallest value then it will return the smallest value instead of the 2nd smallest value.

Example: If I have values `5, 4, 2, 1, 1`, `Small(Range;2)` will return 1 when I want 2.

is there a way I can either filter the input of the Small function or is there a different function that'll do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Hmm - basically, you want to apply the SMALL() function to a list of [distinct values](https://superuser.com/questions/238656/openoffice-get-distinct-values-from-column), right?