# Count unique names in excel column range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spread sheet that contains a list of server names in column B. 
The server names appear multiple times in this column.

I would like to count the number of *unique server names in a give range*.

The range is `B2:B1400`

I tried this but it returned 0

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B2:B1400,B2:B1400)>0,1))
```

Would someone know how?

Comment: You can always do "remove duplicates" this will tell you how many items were removed

Comment: The formula you suggested is valid but only for counting distinct **numbers** in the range - for text or numbers (or a combination of both) you can use the formula I suggest below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FREQUENCY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/frequency-HP005209097.aspx) doesn't work like that.

One of the quickest ways to get the distinct count would be to first filter out the duplicates and then select the records, right-click on bottom bar of Excel and check 'Count'.

See this post for [getting the distinct values in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-excel).

---

**UPDATE:**
There are a bunch of ways you could achieve this..
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/

Answer (score 10):

This formula will give you a "distinct count" without any helper columns

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B1400<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:B1400,B2:B1400&""))`

Comment: How does this work? SUMPRODUCT takes a 2D array, right? (B2:B1400<>"") produces an array of TRUE/FALSE values, but what is the division operator doing, and what about the concatenation? Is that a trick to get COUNTIF to generate an array instead of a single value?

Comment: I tried to explain how it works in another answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel/18588144#18588144

Answer (score 1):

Add a second column with

```
=1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$1400;B2)
```

and then sum the column.

Each row will have a value corresponding to it's fraction of the total number of similar occurrences. The sum of all rows will give you the distinct count.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has probably been answered but I was wrestling with this and found the following formula helpful.

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0),MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0))>0,1))

Basically putting the MATCH formula instead of the cell references. Also found a video on YouTube https://youtu.be/r51RdvOONRQ

Answer (score 1):

Modern answer that makes it really simple (requires Excel 365, Excel 2021, or newer):

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B2:B1400))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below as an array:

```
{=SUM(1/COUNTIF(B2:B1400,B2:B1400))}
```

No need for any helper columns, however, the larger the range the more calculations it will need to iterate through.; but that is true for an array formula.