# How can I count unique values in one column based on criteria in two other columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to to count the number of unique entries in column A where Column C says NO and column D says YES. However, I cannot devise a formula to do this based on two different criteria.  How could I do something like this?

For instance, I want to know the number of unique countries that have viewed an event on-demand but not live, which would be 4 in the following example:

```
country  |  Preview  |  Live  |  On Demand
GB       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES
GB       |  NO       |  YES   |  YES
ES       |  NO       |  YES   |  YES
DE       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES
FR       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES
US       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES
```

From the formulas suggested in the answer below I have managed to get excel to accept the following formula but this does not return a value. The aim of this is to enter a 1 in column F if E is equal to 1. Any help would be appreciated:

```
=IF(E=1, IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A214, A2:A214, 0), MATCH(A2:A214, A2:A214, 0)) > 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: if VBA is OK then a "Collection"-object provides an easy possibility to count the number of unique entries

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  There will be lots of identical entries. For example GB NO YES will appear many times

Comment: I had a quick look at VBA but i have never used this before.  Whilst it looks very powerful it would be great if there was a simple formula for this

Comment: Just to clarify what I need here: There will be many individuals from each country with the same or different criteria. In a separate worksheet is a summary of key details which includes the number of unique countries that have watched the event.  In that summary sheet I need a simple number to show how many unique countries have watched the event on demand only. And so I need a formula to get this number.

Comment: the VBA-code below does exactly what you want. but if you want to have pure excel-functions, you must use array functions (F2 /  Ctrl+Shift+Enter) SUM, IF, FREQUENCY, MATCH . . .

Comment: see extra answer below

Comment: If you find a answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer. You help answerers to get reputation, and other questionaires to find their answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider adding a formula that simply comonbines values of both columns, and another that counts new/unique values?

Formula for E `=$C:$C&$D:$D`

Formula for F `=IF(COUNTIF(E$1:E2,E2)=1,1,0)` ( this is example fopr cell( F2)

```
country  |  Preview  |  Live  |  On Demand | Combined | New/unique
GB       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES       | NOYES    | 1
GB       |  NO       |  YES   |  YES       | YESYES   | 1
ES       |  NO       |  YES   |  YES       | YESYES   | 0
DE       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES       | NOYES    | 0
FR       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES       | NOYES    | 0
US       |  NO       |  NO    |  YES       | NOYES    | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following array formula to get the count of unique records meeting all criteria. Paste the following into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C8="NO")*(D2:D8="YES")/IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,A2:A8,C2:C8,"NO",D2:D8,"YES")=0,1,COUNTIFS(A2:A8,A2:A8&"",C2:C8,"NO",D2:D8,"YES")))
```

It's long and a little repetitive, but it should work for you. This formula uses the `1/COUNTIF(...)` trick that's shown up [many](https://superuser.com/q/189762/76571) [times](https://superuser.com/q/520486/76571) on this site in the past for counting unique records. I had to introduce the repetitive `IF` condition to keep from getting `#DIV/0!` errors.

*What the formula does:*

`SUMPRODUCT` with one array argument just adds the elements of the array. The multiplication terms go to 0 if either condition is not met, and 1 if they are both met. The division by the `COUNTIFS` is a way of scaling this value to get the unique count. For instance, if there were two records for `GB` with On Demand but not Live, each of those records would get scaled down to count as `1/2` of a record in the total sum. If there were three such records, each would count as `1/3`. That way when the sum adds these records, the total sum for `GB` On Demand but not Live will be 1, e.g. `1/2`+`1/2`=`1`. This is how uniqueness is captured.

Answer (score 0):

create a Makro and name it "CountMyUniqueEntries" open the VBA-Editor and copy the following code snippet into Module1:

```
Sub CountMyUniqueEntries()
    Dim cells As Range: Set cells = Excel.Selection
    'the selection does only contain data, no column-headers
    Dim i
    Dim uniqueCountries As New Collection
    For i = 1 To cells.Rows.Count
        Dim Live As Boolean: Live = (UCase(cells(i, 3)) = "YES")
        Dim OnDemand As Boolean: OnDemand = (UCase(cells(i, 4)) = "YES")
        Dim country As String: country = UCase(cells(i, 1))
        If Not Live And OnDemand Then
            If Not Contains(uniqueCountries, country) Then
                uniqueCountries.Add country, country
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "The number of unique countries is: " & uniqueCountries.Count 
End Sub
Private Function Contains(col As Collection, ByVal entry As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsEmpty(col(entry)) Then: 'DoNothing
    Contains = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

maybe you have to activate the menu "Developer-Tools" in the "Options" first

Answer (score 0):

Can you create another column with a formula of the sort

```
IF(<Condition>,Actual Value,Placeholder Value)
```

And then, take the number of distinct values in this column and subtract 1 from it?

So, if your condition is true, the actual value reaches this column, else a placeholder value does. You can then take a count of the distinct values

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks like it could be helpful, but I am not sure how to implement it. i.e. what the condition is or the values should be.

Answer (score 0):

this tends to be a rather complex formula. I will split it into pieces, so it will be more clear and obvious how this works.
you have already 4 columns A, B, C, D. You will need four more columns E, F, G, H.

In column E copy this formula to every cell (copy using +sign right bottom of first cell):

```
=IF(C2="NO", IF(D2="YES", 1, 0), 0)
```

In column F copy this formula to the first cell:

```
=IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A8, A2:A8, 0), MATCH(A2:A8, A2:A8, 0)) > 0, 1, 0)
```

select every cell of column F press "F2" and after that press "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter"

in column G copy this formula to every cell:

```
=IF(E2=1, IF(F2=1, 1, 0), 0)
```

use an extra cell, maybe in column H and sum the 1's of G together with:

```
=SUM(G:G)
```

have fun

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  This formula does not seem to work because column F will only count the first occurrence of the unique country, regardless of whether the view was live or on demand.  Column G therefore does not sum correctly as a correct on demand view may include a subsequent occurrence of a country that has already been identified as unique in a previous row.

Comment: please read the most important words:

Comment: press "F2" and after that press "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter"

Comment: maybe I do not understand your problem well enough but I don't have to. anyway, others can only give you an idea to the right direction. you have to adopt the ideas to your specific problem.

Comment: Oh thanks.  I did of course read all of your words and follow your instructions.  And try to adopt and adapt your ideas to create the correct solution. Unfortunately your suggestion was flawed and I could not adapt a correct solution. Oh well