# Remove duplicates after filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

After using this formula `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),A2,"")`  in column C, it nicely filters out the blacklisted numbers.

But I need advice for a step further:  How do I remove duplicates?

Comment: I have a couple of suggestions for improving the question i.e. to help  others help you.   1) Include the version of Office that your are using.  2) Include the data as text (nobody wants to type them all in)   3) Let us know what you've already tried after researching the question.

Comment: @nixda  thanks for the macro.  is it possible to include the filtering out a blacklist in the same macro too?

Comment: @user245491 I have posted a working version for your case

Answer (score 1):

Try using the advanced filter as described by Microsoft:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262277

#### To create a compiled list of unique records, follow these steps:

1. Select the column titles above rows or records that you want to
   sort.
2. On the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Advanced Filter.
   If you are prompted as follows, click OK.   No headers detected.
   Assume top row of selection is header row?
3. Under Action, click Copy to another location.
4. Click to select the Unique records only check box.
5. In the List range box, type or select the range of records (such as
   A3:H10).
6. In the Criteria range box, type or select the same range of records
   (that is, A3:H10)
7. In the Copy to box, type the address of or select the first cell
   where you want the information to be placed. Make sure there is
   enough room so you don't overwrite pre-existing data.

   Have in mind, that you can only do this in the active sheet.
8. Click OK.

**Notes**

If the first record of original data is duplicated, it appears twice in the new list. Just hide the first line.

If you perform the Advanced Filter command in-place, the sheet still contains all records. Duplicate records are hidden. To work around this behavior, point to Rows on the Format menu, and then click Unhide.

Comment: noted your comments.  done the advanced filtering nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Original code** (to remove duplicates from a column: https://superuser.com/a/49618/50173)

```
'Remove duplicates from SORTED list
Sub getDistinct()
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            ActiveCell.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

#### Modification

In the line `If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value` the macro checks if the next cell below the current one has the same value. If yes, it deletes the current one and moves on to the next cell.

You can add a second condition to the IF statement, so it would also delete cells which are in your blacklist. Here's the pseudocode.

```
if ActiveCell = NextCell OR ActiveCell = FoundinBlacklist then delete Activecell
```

#### Final code

```
Sub getDistinct()
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        On Error Resume Next
        Set foundit = Range("B2:B7").Find(ActiveCell, lookat:=xlWhole)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) Or Not foundit Is Nothing Then
            ActiveCell.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If   
    Loop
End Sub
```

#### Notes

1. To use VBA macros go to `Developer » Visual basic` » paste the code somewhere
2. Have in mind, that this code only works for sorted lists.  So sort your data column before.
3. You have to put your cursor at the start of your list and run the macro via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
4. You have to change `Range("B2:B7")` accordingly to the range of your own blacklist
5. You can easily switch from blacklist to whitelist concept by removing the `Not` from `Not 
   foundit Is Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the formula to:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)) * ISNA(MATCH(A2,C$1:C1,0)),A2,"")
```

It won't display duplicated records. You can then use AutoFilter, excluding `(Blanks)`, and copy&paste values to a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the followings:**

1. *Write this Formula in `B2` & fill it down.*

   =Countif(A$2:A2,A2)
2. `Counif` function will generate list of `1's` & `2's`, now you need to delete the rows for which the count is greater than `1`.
3. Click on the `Filter` button in the `Data Tab` to apply the `Autofilter`.
4. From `column B` select rows that are not equal to `1`.
5. You can then Delete these rows by highlighting them, and selecting `Delete Rows`.
6. Finally remove the `Filter`& you will be left with Unique Cell numbers.