# How do I sort out duplicates using a formula in excel? Listing the unique values in adjacent cells. Without using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

Pretty often I want to pick unique values from a table and list them in another, mostly to make statistics or summaries. A child can do this manually, shouldn't be too hard a task for my computer to do the same thing? Of course I may use VB, control buttons ect, but this is not very user friendly when shared with other users, and security settings confuse even more.

Answer (score 2):

Data Tab - Sort & Filter Group - Advanced - copy to another location - unique records only - OK

Answer (score 0):

This formula checks for duplicate entries using `COUNTIF` and `MAX` and a range which moves subsequently downwards. The last entry will be kept.

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A65536,A1:A65536))>1,"",A1)
```

Assuming your data is in column A: Copy the formula to B1 and use autofill down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See also, this question here - including my alternative approach using pivot tables:

[How do I get the distinct values in a column in Excel?](https://superuser.com/a/577794/151054)

If you've customised your shortcuts/ribbon/QAT in Excel to add an 'Insert PivotTable' shortcut, this can be a very speedy way to get unique records.