# Extract distinct categories and subcategories dynamically from a table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following table:

```
FRUIT  COLOR  TOT
Apple  red    2
Apple  red    14
Apple  green  22
Grape  black  1
Grape  black  4
Grape  black  4
```

I want to dynamically populate a summary sheet like this:

```
FRUIT  COLOR  TOT
Apple  red    16
Apple  green  22
Grape  black  9
```

So essentially I need to extract with a dynamic formula distinct categories (fruit) and the relative subcategories (color), so that if I add in the first table a new row with:

```
Banana  yellow  5
```

It will be automatically added to the summary.

Kinda like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel) question, but I need it dynamic and with also sub-category.. With only categories I already succeeded in doing it, the real problem are subcategories..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any formula. Just use the tools that Excel provides.

1. Select your data
2. Click `Insert > Table`
3. Click on one of the cell of the table
4. Click `Insert > Pivot Table`
5. In the rows, add the fields `FRUIT` and `COLOR`
6. In the values, add the field `TOT`
7. Configure the layout of the pivot table to fit your needs

When you add a new value to your data table (preferably at the end of the table), the table will automatically extend. Then, right click on the pivot table and click on `Refresh`.

Alternatively, you can update the pivot table using the `Refresh All` button in the `Data` tab.

---

**Documentation:**

1. [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data (Microsoft)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)
2. [Pivot Tables in Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

---

**Example:**

[image]